# Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' not found

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

I am Using `PasswordResetView` for reset password, but when I Enter new Password and submit the button. Django redirect to this [image: page]

**ulrs.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from Authentication import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_view
from .forms import *

app_name = 'Authentication'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.loginpage, name='loginpage'),
    path('login', views.handlelogin, name='login'),
    path('logout', views.handlelogout, name='logout'),
    path('password_reset', views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),

    path('password_reset/done/',
         auth_view.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='Authentication_template/password_reset_done.html'),
         name='password_reset_done'),

    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_view.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='Authentication_template/password_reset.html',
                                                    form_class=SetPasswordForm), name='password_reset_confirm'),

    path('password_reset_complete/', auth_view.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
        template_name='Authentication_template/password_reset_complete.html'),
         name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

here I use custom view for sending email to user.

Comment: You have set `app_name = 'Authentication'` meaning you have **namespaced** those urls. So you now need to refer to them as `Authentication:password_reset_complete` instead of `password_reset_complete`, etc. See [URL namespaces (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat i know namespace things, but here problem is different, when i submit password reset form it must redirect to ```password_reset_complete/```, but it's give me error which is in screenshot

Comment: The problem is the namespace. You get the error because the view itself tries to reverse the url as `reverse_lazy('password_reset_complete')` while instead due to your namespace it needs to be `reverse_lazy('Authentication:password_reset_complete')`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set `app_name = 'Authentication'` meaning you have **namespaced** those urls. So you now need to refer to them as `Authentication:password_reset_complete` instead of `password_reset_complete`, etc. See [URL namespaces (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)

One solution would be to remove the line `app_name = 'Authentication'`, if you wish to keep those lines you would need to set the `success_url` for the views yourself, you can pass it as a kwarg to `as_view`:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
    auth_view.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name='Authentication_template/password_reset.html',
        form_class=SetPasswordForm,
        success_url = reverse_lazy('Authentication:password_reset_complete')
    ), name='password_reset_confirm'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using the wrong path name for your password_reset_complete.

Instead of path('password_reset_complete/'...

Try with:

```
path('reset/done/', auth_view.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
    template_name='Authentication_template/password_reset_complete.html'),
     name='password_reset_complete')
```